# Differential equation with some constraints

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ as functions of $t$, satisfying the following conditions:
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha+\beta+\gamma & = 0 \\
\sin^2\alpha + \sin^2\beta + \sin^2\gamma & = c^2 \\
\left| \frac{d}{dt}(\sin\alpha,\sin\beta,\sin\gamma)\right| & = 1
\end{align}
$$
I'm thinking of $c^2$ as *small*.  At the very least that means $<2$, and intuitively it means $\ll 2$.  Some geometry shows that there is a qualitative change in the nature of the solutions when $c^2$ goes from $<2$ to $>2$.

Comment: Would it be unsatisfactory to numerically compute the one-dimensional manifold defined by the first two constraints, and then compute a unit speed trajectory along that path?

Comment: @Rahul: Not necessarily.  But if that's all that can be done, it might be of interest to _know_ that that's all that can be done.  Also, if the solution is a function with interesting properties, maybe something could be said about those.......

Comment: Well, the simpler-looking problem $\lvert d(x,y)/dt \rvert = 1$ with $ax^2 + by^2 = 1$ is equivalent to finding the arc length parametrization of an ellipse, which is hard. So I'm not very hopeful for a nice solution to this problem, but maybe someone else has better ideas...

Comment: I'm not sure your proposed "simpler-looking" problem is actually simpler.